# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps(

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sparkcore

I am new to scala and getting below error for code in INTELLJ can any one please help to resolve it

```
     import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
     object wordcount {
     def main(args: Array[String])
      {
      val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("TestSpark")
      .set("spark.executor.memory","2g")

       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
       val a  = sc.parallelize(Seq("This is the firstline", "This is the  
       second line", "This is the third line"))              
       val count = a.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
       val counts = count.map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
        counts.foreach(println)

       }

       }
```

I am getting below error :

```
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    
     scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)
      Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCallSite(Utils.scala:1342)
     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:81)
     at wordcount$.main(wordcount.scala:12)
     at wordcount.main(wordcount.scala)
     Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-
```

Below is my built SBT

```
      name := "scalaprograms"

      version := "1.0"

       scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

      libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" %
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 12):

You should use Scala 2.11 in order to work with`spark-core_2.11`. I.e. use :

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

AFAIk Spark does not work yet with Scala 2.12

Comment: Thanks this worked

Comment: Manoj - Can you please mark this as an accepted answer?

Comment: @Manoj4068 can you accept this answer?