# Compatible Scala version for Spark 2.2.0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Which Scala version works with Spark 2.2.0 ?
I'm getting following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;

Comment: Is that happening with scala test ?

Comment: I got this error fixed and now came up with a new one.The error was removed by adding dependency in build.sbt

Comment: I'm still getting the error, I think it's version conflict, but tried everything and it still didn't worked.

Comment: similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192915/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-refarrayop)

Comment: name := "Scala-Spark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"

copy & paste this in build.sbt. It will definately work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark 2.2.0 is built and distributed to work with Scala 2.11 by default. To write applications in Scala, you will need to use a compatible Scala version (e.g. 2.11.X). And your scala version might be 2.12.X. That's why it is throwing exception.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/):

> Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API,
>   **Spark 2.2.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala
>   version (2.11.x).**

Answer (score 1):

To select appropriate scala version for your spark application one could run `spark-shell` on the target server. Desired scala version is contained in the welcome message:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_152)
```

It is `2.11.8` in my Spark distributive.

Also there are pages on MVN repository contained scala version for one's spark distribution:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.2.0 needs Java 8+ and scala 2.11. Thats about the version info.

But, looking at your error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ", it seems your Spark is unable to find the driver class.

Probably you should be looking in this direction rather than versions.